# DropDownListFor not returning a Selected Value in Modified Scaffold Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core

I am rather new to Razor and I'm using the default templates. I have a ViewModel which contains three models:

```
public class CarAndOwnerViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cars { get; set; }
        public SelectListItem SelectedCar { get; set; }
        public OwnerModel Person{ get; set; }
    }
```

I am using this ViewModel in my create method. To get the list of Cars I use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.SeletedCar, new SelectList(Model.Cars, "Value", "Text", Model.Cars))
```

When I submit this drop down list the value of CarAndOwnerViewModel.SelectedCar is null. I Have a textbox that contains the following and it has it in CarAndOwnerViewModel.Owner.Name:

```
<input asp-for="Owner.Naame" class="form-control" />
```

What I filled out in that input box is passed on. I am not sure why the Input Boxes are working but the Select box isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `SelectedCar` should be an `int` instead of a `SelectedItem`

Changing the class to

```
public class CarAndOwnerViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cars { get; set; }
        public int SelectedCar { get; set; }
        public OwnerModel Person{ get; set; }
    }
```

Fixed the issue.